# How to use SharedPreferences() to store value and get stored value to another activity

Tags: android

I'am trying to store a value of edit text using shared preferences but I don't know how to get stored value of SharedPreferences() in another activity.

Comment: did you try anything? any code?

Comment: Is it the very next activity you are trying to pass the value ?

Comment: Yes I tried. I know how to store value to SharedPreferences but I don't know how to get stored value.

Comment: create shared preference class, store data then use it every where

Comment: It is the very next activity but I'm using my background worker to open an intent

Comment: Can you give me example on how to use it on another activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: i wrote some answer for you try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First intialize `SharedPreferences` with a `Context`:

```
final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext);
```

To save you could use this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("editText", yourEditText.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Then to get the value inside another class, you could use:

```
String editText = preferences.getString("editText", "");
```

The second value `""` represents a default value, if `editText` is not saved earlier, an empty `String` will be returned.

Comment: Do I need to put final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext);
On every activity that I'm going to get value from?

Comment: Yes, you can do that!

Comment: I cannot get stored value

Comment: private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = loginPreferences.getString("username", "");
I use this code.

Comment: @RamonDareneDelaCruz use mine. I didn't use MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: It's okay now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in an App that may get complex further down the way, it is better to centralize your shared preferences. So I suggest to make a class for shared preferences like this:

**Java Class**

```
//SharedPreferences manager class
public class SharedPrefs {

//SharedPreferences file name
private static String SHARED_PREFS_FILE_NAME = "my_app_shared_prefs";

//here you can centralize all your shared prefs keys
public static String KEY_MY_SHARED_BOOLEAN = "my_shared_boolean";
public static String KEY_MY_SHARED_FOO = "my_shared_foo";

//get the SharedPreferences object instance
//create SharedPreferences file if not present


private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

//Save Booleans
public static void putBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getPrefs(context).edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();       
}

//Get Booleans
public static boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key) {
    return getPrefs(context).getBoolean(key, false);
}

//Get Booleans if not found return a predefined default value
public static boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    return getPrefs(context).getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

//Strings
public static void putString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getPrefs(context).edit().putString(key, value).commit();
}

public static String getString(Context context, String key) {
    return getPrefs(context).getString(key, "");
}

public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
    return getPrefs(context).getString(key, defaultValue);
}

//Integers
public static void putString(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(key, value).commit();
}

public static int getInt(Context context, String key) {
    return getPrefs(context).getInt(key, 0);
}

public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    return getPrefs(context).getInt(key, defaultValue);
}

//Floats
public static void putFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
    getPrefs(context).edit().putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float getFloat(Context context, String key) {
    return getPrefs(context).getFloat(key, 0);
```

In your activity you may save SharedPreferences this way

**Save a variable**

```
//saving a boolean into prefs
SharedPrefs.putBoolean(this, SharedPrefs.KEY_MY_SHARED_BOOLEAN, booleanVar);
```

and you may retrieve your SharedPreferences this way

**Retrieve a saved value**

```
//getting a boolean from prefs
booleanVar = SharedPrefs.getBoolean(this,SharedPrefs.KEY_MY_SHARED_BOOLEAN);
```

This way you won't have scattered shared preference code, sometimes with different structure all over the App.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna try it. I'm still learning about android studio. I'am working on online ordering application with sms as my thesis right now.

Comment: Do I need to declare SharedPreferences in the activity I'm going to get the stored value from?
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
Like this?

Comment: Not exactly, you should create a new java class (right click on com.yourdomain.yourapp ->New->Java Class) with the first code section called SharedPrefs, in your activities you should just import SharedPrefs (import com.yourdomain.yourapp.SharedPrefs) and just save the value you want to keep like in the 2nd section and recover it like in the 3rd section above

Comment: Oh, okay I understand now. I don't need to put it in every activity because it is saved in a class. Thank you for this, this will make my codes organized.

Answer (score 0):

```
// store the value in preference store

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("key", "value");
    editor.commit();

// get the value from preference store

    String name = sharedpreferences .getString("key", "");
```

Comment: this is the code to put string?

loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);

Comment: I would be able to get the stored value if I put,    String name = sharedpreferences .getString("username", "");

Comment: yes right , you also need to use loginPrefsEditor.commit() statement to save the value in pref store

Comment: Okay I will try that. If I use this,     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("key", "value");
    editor.commit(); 
To get value of my username in edit text, I can use the stored value even if my intent is in the background worker?

Comment: why are you using intent at the first place ?

Comment: I'm using intent on onPostExecute() of my background worker to check the result of my php code and open another activity.

Comment: onPostExecute() runs on UI thread so you can start a new activity from this method . If you want to get the saved value from shared preference , it will work on UI as well as worker thread

Comment: I cant get stored value of SharedPreferences in background worker?

Comment: paste your entire code here then we will be able to help you , though you can use shared preference in whatever thread you want

Answer (score 0):

here is my try, create class of SF

```
public class SFData {

public static SharedPreferences sf_login;
static SharedPreferences.Editor sf_login_edit;

public static void loginSF(Context ctx){
    sf_login = ctx.getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
    sf_login_edit = sf_login.edit();
}

public static void loginSFStore(Map<String, Object> mapData){
    loginSFClear();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapData.entrySet()) {
        String keyName = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof String) {
            sf_login_edit.putString(keyName, (String) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            sf_login_edit.putBoolean(keyName, (boolean) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            sf_login_edit.putInt(keyName, (int) value);
        }
    }
    sf_login_edit.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
    sf_login_edit.commit();
}

public static void loginSFClear(){
    sf_login_edit.clear();
    sf_login_edit.commit();
}

}
```

sample of use
`Boolean login = SFData.sf_login.getBoolean("isLogin", false);`
please adapt to your code

Comment: If I store a username on SharedPreferences, I can use it in any activity? What are the limits of SharedPreferences? Will username be erased when I close application?

Comment: it will remain until clear cache data on apps config

Comment: Okay I will try it now

Comment: @ntaloventi not true. It will only be deleted if the user clears ALL application data, not only cache.

Comment: if I use editor.clear() will it delete stored values?

Comment: I used sample above cause my apps is trigger by web also, so if change on web apps, I should clear then store new data on android apps, that's why I'm using clear